# How to find out the dynamic libraries executables loads when run?

Tags: executable, libraries, dynamic-linking

I want to find out the list of dynamic libraries a binary loads when run (With their full paths). I am using CentOS 6.0. How to do this?

Answer (score 180):

You can do this with `ldd` command:

```
NAME
       ldd - print shared library dependencies

SYNOPSIS
       ldd [OPTION]...  FILE...

DESCRIPTION
       ldd  prints  the  shared  libraries  required by each program or shared
       library specified on the command line.
....
```

Example:

```
$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff87ffe000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ff0510c1000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff050eb9000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007ff050cb0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff0508f0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff0506ec000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff0512f7000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff0504ce000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007ff0502c9000)
```

Comment: Any idea of what would be a macOS equivalent of this? No `lld` on darwin, it appears, nor can I find it via homebrew.

Comment: On macOS: `otool -L <path-to-binary>`

Comment: be aware that this may execute the binary. So if the binary is untrusted, it may be better to not use `ldd`. See [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html).

Comment: To follow @PaulRooney 's comment: In particular, the man page suggests using `objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED` as an alternative to ldd if you do not trust the executable.

Comment: I used this snippet to locate the deps and then copy them to my jail...
`ldd ${jail}/bin/* | egrep -o '\[^ \]*/lib\[^ \]*\[.\]\[0-9\]' | xargs -I{} -P1 sudo cp -v {} ${jail}{}`

Comment: readelf is better for checking cross compile executables https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220110/432225

Comment: `lddtree` from `pax-utils` is better when you want to see the hierarchical tree of dependencies including dependencies' dependencies; plain `ldd` shows only the immediate dependencies.

Comment: where is it gettin `linux-vdso.so.1` from? Don't see any path nor is it next to executable.

Answer (score 118):

**`readelf -d $executable | grep 'NEEDED'`**

Can be used if you can't run the executable, e.g. if it was cross compiled, or if you don't trust it:

> In  the  usual case, ldd invokes the standard dynamic linker (see ld.so(8)) with the LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS environment variable set to 1, which causes the linker to display the library
>          dependencies.  Be aware, however, that in some circumstances, some versions of ldd may attempt to obtain the dependency information by directly executing the program.  Thus,  you  should
>          never employ ldd on an untrusted executable, since this may result in the execution of arbitrary code.

Example:

```
readelf -d /bin/ls | grep 'NEEDED'
```

Sample ouptut:

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libacl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Note that libraries can depend on other libraries, so now you need to find the dependencies.

A naive approach that often works is:

```
$ locate libselinux.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/mnt/debootstrap/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
```

but the more precise method is to understand the `ldd` search path / cache. I think `ldconfig` is the way to go.

Choose one, and repeat:

```
readelf -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 | grep 'NEEDED'
```

Sample output:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpcre.so.3]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

And so on.

See also:

- [Determine direct shared object dependencies of a Linux binary? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242761/how-do-i-find-the-direct-shared-object-dependencies-of-a-linux-elf-binary)
- [How can I find the dynamic libraries required by an ELF Binary in C++? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612735/how-can-i-find-the-dynamic-libraries-required-by-an-elf-binary-in-c)
- [How to know which dynamic libraries are needed by an ELF? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172649/how-to-know-which-dynamic-libraries-are-needed-by-an-elf)

**`/proc/<pid>/maps` for running processes**

[Mentioned by Basile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373184/32558), this is useful to find all the libraries currently being used by running executables. E.g.:

```
sudo awk '/\.so/{print $6}' /proc/1/maps | sort -u
```

shows all currently loaded dynamic dependencies of `init` (PID `1`):

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.4.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmod.so.2.3.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2.2.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

This method also shows libraries opened with `dlopen`, tested with [this minimal setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/71ab01c5de024d9d97f0e2f0698cbee6c6a9c87a/shared-library/basic/dlopen.c#L16) hacked up with a `sleep(1000)` on Ubuntu 18.04.

See also: [How to see the currently loaded shared objects in Linux? | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/310199/see-currently-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux/1243089)

Comment: Nice part about readelf method is that it works on cross-binaries (ex: armhf on amd64) as well

Comment: +1 for deep diving into elf binary itself rather than relying on linker or other tools.

Comment: Great, `readelf` worked on shared libs too.

Answer (score 28):

ldd and lsof show the libraries loaded either *directly* or at a *given moment*.  They do not account for libraries loaded via [`dlopen` (or discarded by `dlclose`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)).  You can get a better picture of this using `strace`, e.g.,

```
strace -e trace=open myprogram
```

(since `dlopen` ultimately calls `open` - though you may of course have a system using different names for 64-bit opens...).

Example:

```
strace -e trace=open date
```

shows me this:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 3
Wed Apr 12 04:56:32 EDT 2017
```

from which one could grep the ".so" names to just see shared objects.

Comment: An improvement: `strace -e trace=open,openat myprogram`

Comment: Nice method. `/proc/<pid>/maps` also shows `dlopen` libs btw: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run/220110#220110 `ltrace -S` output is even cooler as it shows both syscalls and library calls like `dlopen`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226524/what-system-call-is-used-to-load-libraries-in-linux/462710#462710

Answer (score 15):

**lsof** also can show you which libraries are being used for one particular process.

i.e.

```
$ pidof nginx
6920 6919

$ lsof -p 6919|grep mem
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64    65960     43 /lib64/libnss_files-2.12.so
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64    19536     36 /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64    10312   1875 /lib64/libfreebl3.so
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64  1923352     38 /lib64/libc-2.12.so
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64    88600   1034 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64  1967392   1927 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64   183080   1898 /lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64    40400   1217 /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.so
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64   142688     77 /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
nginx   6919 root  mem    REG               0,64   154664     31 /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

Answer (score 3):

#### For mass query:

1. create a small script (`useslib`) and put in in the PATH (orspecify a full path in the command below)

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   ldd $1 | grep -q $2
   exit $?
   ```
2. Use it in a `find` command, for instance:

   ```
   find /usr/bin/ -executable -type f -exec useslib {} libgtk-x11-2.0 \; -print
   ```

(libgtk-x11-2.0 seems to be the gtk2 lib)

Answer (score 3):

For a *process* of pid 1234, you could also read the `/proc/1234/maps` (textual) pseudo-file (read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) or use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)

This gives the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of that process, hence the files (including shared libraries, even [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ed one) which are memory mapped

(of course, use `ps aux` or [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) to find the processes running some given program)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible use `pmap`.

For example, start a process: `$ watch date`

Get pid: `$ ps -ef | grep watch`

Show memory map: `$ pmap <pid>`

Show with full path: `$ pmap <pid> -p`

```
$ pmap 72770
72770:   watch date
00005613a32c9000     20K r-x-- watch
00005613a34cd000      4K r---- watch
00005613a34ce000      4K rw--- watch
00005613a4f6a000    264K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2f3a7d5000 204616K r---- locale-archive
00007f2f46fa7000   1748K r-x-- libc-2.27.so
00007f2f4715c000   2048K ----- libc-2.27.so
00007f2f4735c000     16K r---- libc-2.27.so
00007f2f47360000      8K rw--- libc-2.27.so
00007f2f47362000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2f47366000     12K r-x-- libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f47369000   2044K ----- libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f47568000      4K r---- libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f47569000      4K rw--- libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f4756a000    160K r-x-- libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47592000   2048K ----- libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47792000     16K r---- libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47796000      4K rw--- libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47797000    232K r-x-- libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f477d1000   2048K ----- libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f479d1000      4K r---- libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f479d2000      4K rw--- libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f479d3000    148K r-x-- ld-2.27.so
00007f2f47bdb000     20K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2f47bf1000     28K r--s- gconv-modules.cache
00007f2f47bf8000      4K r---- ld-2.27.so
00007f2f47bf9000      4K rw--- ld-2.27.so
00007f2f47bfa000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffd39404000    136K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffd3959b000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffd3959e000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total           215692K
```

```
$ pmap 72770 -p
72770:   watch date
00005613a32c9000     20K r-x-- /usr/bin/watch
00005613a34cd000      4K r---- /usr/bin/watch
00005613a34ce000      4K rw--- /usr/bin/watch
00005613a4f6a000    264K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2f3a7d5000 204616K r---- /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
00007f2f46fa7000   1748K r-x-- /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so
00007f2f4715c000   2048K ----- /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so
00007f2f4735c000     16K r---- /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so
00007f2f47360000      8K rw--- /usr/lib64/libc-2.27.so
00007f2f47362000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2f47366000     12K r-x-- /usr/lib64/libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f47369000   2044K ----- /usr/lib64/libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f47568000      4K r---- /usr/lib64/libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f47569000      4K rw--- /usr/lib64/libdl-2.27.so
00007f2f4756a000    160K r-x-- /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47592000   2048K ----- /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47792000     16K r---- /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47796000      4K rw--- /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.6.1
00007f2f47797000    232K r-x-- /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f477d1000   2048K ----- /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f479d1000      4K r---- /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f479d2000      4K rw--- /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6.1
00007f2f479d3000    148K r-x-- /usr/lib64/ld-2.27.so
00007f2f47bdb000     20K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f2f47bf1000     28K r--s- /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
00007f2f47bf8000      4K r---- /usr/lib64/ld-2.27.so
00007f2f47bf9000      4K rw--- /usr/lib64/ld-2.27.so
00007f2f47bfa000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffd39404000    136K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffd3959b000     12K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffd3959e000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total           215692K
```

Answer (score 2):

I found `lddtree` from [PaX-utils](https://github.com/HardenedBSD/pax-utils) (package name `pax-utils` on most distros) to be more useful; it prints a hierarchical tree of dependencies (including dependencies' dependencies).  This is better than `ldd` which only lists the binary's immediate dependencies.

```bsh
lddtree $(which ls)

ls => /usr/bin/ls (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

`lddtree` by default skips duplicate dependencies; if you also want that pass `-a`; be ready to tolerate the redundancy and verbosity.

Comment: No command lddtree found

Comment: @CSQGB Do you've `pax-utils` package installed?  Click on PaX-utils link in the answer and check how to install for your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how widespread the `-p` option to ldconfig(8), but the following sh/awk script, using the readelf(1) [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/220110/251091), and ldconfig's `-p`, might be of help if you want to avoid any security issues with ldd(1), but also see the path of the dynamic libraries.  (NB: this does *not* do the transitive closure of inclusion, as it were, so you only see the libraries called out directly by the a.out.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

needs=`readelf -d $1 | \
  awk '$2=="(NEEDED)" {
      gsub("[][]", "", $5); 
      hits[$5]=$5
  }
  END {
      for (i in hits) {
          printf(sprintf("%s ", i))
      }
  }'`

ldconfig -p | \
    awk -vneeds="$needs" \
       'BEGIN{
          split(needs,aneeds)
        }

        { 
          if (!arr[$1]) 
            arr[$1] = $NF
        }

        END { 
          for (i in aneeds) { 
            need = aneeds[i]; 
            if (arr[need]) {
              print need "\t" arr[need]
            } else {
               print "unfulfilled:", need
            }
          }
       }'
```

for example:

```
{1001} ./foo.sh a.out
libc.so.6   /usr/lib/libc.so.6
libX11.so.6 /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
libgdk-3.so.0   /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0
libgcr-base-3.so.1  /usr/lib/libgcr-base-3.so.1
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18  /usr/local/lib/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18
libatk-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0
libharfbuzz.so.0    /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0
libsoup-2.4.so.1    /usr/lib/libsoup-2.4.so.1
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0  /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libgck-1.so.0   /usr/lib/libgck-1.so.0
libgthread-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0
libgcr-ui-3.so.1    /usr/lib/libgcr-ui-3.so.1
libglib-2.0.so.0    /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
libgobject-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
libcairo-gobject.so.2   /usr/lib/libcairo-gobject.so.2
libpango-1.0.so.0   /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0
libz.so.1   /usr/lib/libz.so.1
libgio-2.0.so.0 /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0  /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
libp11-kit.so.0 /usr/lib/libp11-kit.so.0
libcairo.so.2   /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2
libgtk-3.so.0   /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0
libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37 /usr/local/lib/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37
```