# What system call is used to load libraries in Linux?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library, strace, dynamic-loading

In `strace` outputs, the paths to the libraries that executables call are in calls to `open()`. Is this the system call used by executables that are dynamically linked? What about `dlopen()`? `open()` isn't a call I'd have guessed would play a role in the execution of programs.

Answer (score 44):

`dlopen` isn't a system call, it's a library function in the [libdl library](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/dlfcn.h.html). Only system calls show up in `strace`.

On Linux and on many other platforms (especially those that use the ELF format for executables), `dlopen` is implemented by opening the target library with `open()` and mapping it into memory with `mmap()`. `mmap()` is really the critical part here, it's what incorporates the library into the process' address space, so the CPU can execute its code. But you have to `open()` the file before you can `mmap()` it!

Comment: "mmap() is really the critical part": And then the dynamic linker has to do the relocations, initialization and so one (but this is not seen at the system call level).

Comment: Since loading of libraries is done by a library function, I think it is relevant to add that the executable itself and `ld-linux` are mapped by the kernel as part of the `execve` system call.

Comment: mmap as per this answer.  Note also that after "open"-ing each library, some (832) bytes are read prior to the mmap call, I presume to check that the library is valid.

Comment: @kasperd So is the Linux kernel aware of the dynamic loader? Does it call it when application is run? Or does the application itself do that? If the latter, how does another executable have access to the application's memory?

Comment: @Melab Yes, the kernel is aware of the dynamic linker. The kernel will read the path to the dynamic linker from the header of the executable. And the kernel will map both into memory. I don't know whether the entry point which the kernel transfer control to at first is within linker or executable. If I was implementing it, I would probably have the kernel transfer control to an entry point in the linker with a return address on the stack pointing to the entry point of the executable.

Comment: @Melab The executable and the dynamic linker are not running as two separate applications. Both are mapped into a single address space by the kernel. When the kernel transfers control, it is a single process with code mapped from two files. If more libraries are needed (which is pretty much always the case for dynamically linked executables), there will soon be even more files mapped into the address space of this process.

Answer (score 6):

dlopen has nothing to do with shared libraries as you think of them. There are two methods of loading a shared object:

1. You tell the compile-time linker (ld, though usually it's called through the compiler) that you want to use functions from a particular shared library. With this approach, you must know what the name of the library will be at when the compile-time linker is run, but you can call the library's functions as if they were statically linked into your program. When the application is run, the dynamic, run-time linker (ld.so) will be called just before the `main` function is called, and set up the application's process space so that the application will find the functions of the library. This involves `open()`ing the lubrary, and then `mmap()`ing it, followed by setting up some lookup tables.
2. You tell the compile-time linker that you want to link with `libdl`, from which you then (using the first method) can call the `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` functions. With dlopen you get a handle to the library, which you can then use with dlsym to receive a function pointer to a particular function. This method is much more complicated for the programmer than the first method (since you have to do the setup manually, rather than have the linker do it automatically for you), and it also is more fragile (since you don't get the compile-time checks that you're calling functions with the correct argument types as you get in the first method), but the advantage is that you can decide which shared object to load at runtime (or even whether to load it at all), making this an interface meant for plugin type functionality. Finally, the dlopen interface is also less portable than the other way, since its mechanics depend on the exact implementation of the dynamic linker (hence libtool's `libltdl`, which tries to abstract away these differences).

Comment: interesting; so dynamically loaded library are better called dynamically linked libraries, since loading binary files into memory isn't the hard part, making the addresses used in it make sense is. When I ask to load a dynamic library, I am actually asking to link(or unlink) the library into(or out of) my address space.

Answer (score 5):

**`ltrace -S` analysis of a minimal example shows that `mmap` is used in glibc 2.23**

In glibc 2.23, Ubuntu 16.04, running `latrace -S` on a minimal program that uses `dlopen` with:

```
ltrace -S ./dlopen.out
```

shows:

```
dlopen("libcirosantilli_ab.so", 1 <unfinished ...>
SYS_open("./x86_64/libcirosantilli_ab.so", 524288, 06267650550)      = -2
SYS_open("./libcirosantilli_ab.so", 524288, 06267650550)             = 3
SYS_read(3, "\177ELF\002\001\001", 832)                              = 832
SYS_brk(0)                                                           = 0x244c000
SYS_brk(0x246d000)                                                   = 0x246d000
SYS_fstat(3, 0x7fff42f9ce30)                                         = 0
SYS_getcwd("/home/ciro/bak/git/cpp-cheat"..., 128)                   = 54
SYS_mmap(0, 0x201028, 5, 2050)                                       = 0x7f1c323fe000
SYS_mprotect(0x7f1c323ff000, 2093056, 0)                             = 0
SYS_mmap(0x7f1c325fe000, 8192, 3, 2066)                              = 0x7f1c325fe000
SYS_close(3)                                                         = 0
SYS_mprotect(0x7f1c325fe000, 4096, 1)                                = 0
```

so we see immediately that `dlopen` calls `open` + `mmap`.

The awesome `ltrace` tool traces both library calls and system calls, and is therefore perfect to examine what is going on in this case.

A closer analysis shows that `open` returns the file descriptor `3` (next free one after stdin, out and err).

`read` then uses that file descriptor, but [TODO why `mmap`'s arguments are limited to four, and we can't see which fd was used there since that is the 5th argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861263/how-to-make-ltrace-s-show-all-arguments-of-system-calls). `strace` confirms as expected that `3` is the one, and the order of the universe is restored.

Brave souls can also venture into glibc code, but I could not find the `mmap` after a quick grep and I'm lazy.

Tested with this [minimal example with build boilerplate on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/81ab30c55634db24216e89ada1e0f271cac074e7/shared-library/basic/dlopen.c).

Answer (score 4):

Today, most operating systems use the method for shared libraries introduced in late 1987 by SunOS-4.0. This method is based on mapping memory via mmap().

Given the fact that in the early 1990s, Sun did even donate the old a.out based code (Solaris at that time was already ELF based) to the FreeBSD people and that this code later was handed over to many other systems (including Linux), you may understand why there is no big difference between platforms.

Answer (score 2):

`strace` reports on system calls (i.e. functions implemented directly by the kernel).  Dynamic libraries aren't a kernel function; `dlopen` is part of the C library, not the kernel.  The implementation of `dlopen` will call `open` (which is a system call) to open the library file so it can be read.

Comment: Library calls can be seen using `ltrace`.

Comment: @kasperd `ltrace -S` is perfect to analyse this as it also shows syscalls: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462710/32558