# Detect all the OS packages that are needed to be installed in order to use the path

Tags: rpm, opensuse, dependencies, shared-library

Given a path, I want to detect all the OS packages that needed to be installed, in order to use it. For example:

```
> /bin/rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]\n" /usr/bin/tcsh
tcsh
```

Sometimes it does not work. For example:

```
> /bin/rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]\n" /sadd/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
file  /sadd/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so is not owned by any package
```

But looking into the output of `ldd` I see:

```
> ldd /sadd/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007f11f7ffa000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x0000711fff7901000)
        libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => /usr/pkgs/python3/3.7.4/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0 (0x00007ffff7422000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/noelision/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f11ff7205000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f13ff6e60000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff126c5c000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff216a21000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000711ff681e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fff16521000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fff17ddb000)
```

I see that it has `/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0`. So I can do:

```
> /bin/rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]\n" /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
libsqlite3-0
```

Meaning there is a required OS package that should be installed in order to use `/sadd/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Now, I can create a script which runs the above `rpm` command and then the `ldd` command on each path and iterates over that shared libs (might need to use `locate` because sometimes there is not path, like for `linux-vdso.so.1`). But:

1. It is not recommended to use `ldd`.
2. The parsing of the `ldd` output is pretty ugly.

Now, I saw a related [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run) on the matter. I could use `readelf` but same issue.

Is there a better solution to detect all the required OS packages for a given path? I also am using [rpmdep.pl](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-rpmdep/) but it expects to get a package name and returns all the package dependencies. So for now my algorithm is:

1. Run `/bin/rpm -qf --queryformat "[%{NAME}]\n" $path` and get the package name (marked with `$package)`. Also add it to the packages list.
2. Run `rpmdep.pl $package`) and add all the packages to the list.
3. Run `ldd $path` and for each line:

   1. if there is a path (like `libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0`) then go back to step 1 with `/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0`.
   2. if there is no path (like `linux-vdso.so.1`) then try to locate it (using `locate` command) and if found, then go back to step 1 with the path you got.

That way I collect all of the OS packages that are required for a path. It works pretty good but I'm looking for a better/clean approach on solving this task. Also, what do you think of my suggested algorithm?

I'm using OpenSUSE if that matters.

Comment: You shouldn’t find any match for `linux-vdso.so.1`, and that’s normal — it’s [the vDSO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397014/86440), it doesn’t exist on disk.

Comment: @StephenKitt yes I know. Just took it as an example of lib without a path (there are cases where `locate` finds one ore more paths.

Comment: Have you tried using `ltrace`?

Comment: It's pretty likely some libraries have package names that are not the same as what's reflected in ldd. On the other hand, having actually tried this a couple of times, it's unlikely you'll have to do this hunting for the package exercise too much.

Comment: @SirMuffington Hi, how `ltrace` can help here? I don't want to execute each path I want to check.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ cat installer.sh
#! /bin/bash

mkdir -p /tmp/testdir
test -e "$1" || exit 1
zypper --installroot /tmp/testdir install $(rpm -qf "$1")
```

[image: Dependency tree]

Comment: Your answer ended up in my "low quality post" queue ... perhaps you could elaborate a little on why this approach works where the OPs attempt failed :)

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for the answer. I just don't understand how it relevant and helps. Also my zypper does not have the `--installroot` option: `Unknown option '--installroot'`

Comment: This command shows **the entire dependency tree for the package you're interested in**. It perfectly works in OpenSuse Tumbleweed. From what I can gather, it's exactly what the OP wants: *"Given a path, I want to detect all the OS packages that needed to be installed, in order to use it."* I have very little desire to learn the intricacies of zypper. Fefora's yum and now dnf have had almost the same options for more than 10 years, likewise Debian's APT.

Comment: From https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_(plain) : `--installroot dir  Behaves like --root but shares the repositories with the host system.` You may replace it with `--root` if it doesn't work with your Suse. It's quite depressing to give you the answer which I've verified to work and you cannot spend literally 3 minutes figuring out why it doesn't work for you and what can be done to rectify the issue. Sorry, I don't have access to your Suse, nor you've bothered to specify your release.